# Displaying file dates and file sizes

Tags: php, file, date

I have this script which does the job, but I need a few modifications.

When used it lists out the files in the directory, but it also adds at the top:

```
.
..
```

which of course links to upper directories. Is there a way to not display them?

The other things I need it to do:

1. Display the date of the files
2. Display the size of the files
3. Have a delete link next to each file

```
<?php

$dir="../files/uploads/" . $_GET["id"]; // Directory where files are stored

if ($dir_list = opendir($dir))
{
while(($filename = readdir($dir_list)) !== false)
{
?>
<p>
    <a href="<?php echo $_GET["id"] . "/" . $filename; ?>"><?php echo $filename; ?></a> 
</p>
<?php
}
closedir($dir_list);
}

?>
```

Comment: bothered to try? or just want some else to do it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below, I haven't put the delete in as you'll have to decide how you're going to do that as in passing the filename back to the page and checking the Post/Get or whatever. Use unlink($dir . $filename); to delete the file.

```
<?php

$dir="../files/uploads/" . $_GET["id"]; // Directory where files are stored

if ($dir_list = opendir($dir))
{

while(($filename = readdir($dir_list)) !== false)
{

if($filename != "." && $filename != ".." ){
?>
<p>
<a href="<?php echo $_GET["id"] . "/" . $filename; ?>"><?php echo $filename; ?></a>     &nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp; <? echo filesize($dir . $filename); ?>&nbsp;bytes &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp; Modified: <? echo date("Y-m-d",filemtime($dir . $filename)); ?>
</p>
<?php
}

}
closedir($dir_list);
}

?>
```

Comment: Cheers. Threw an error at first but I was able to resolve it. Don't worry it wasn't your fault. It was my directory path.

Well done.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir = '../files/uploads/'.$_GET['id'];
$dir_iterator = new FilesystemIterator($dir,FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS );
foreach($dir_iterator as $file){
    if ($file->isFile()) {
        print_r( $file->getFilename());
        print_r( $file->getSize());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use a recursive iterator here, since you're not actually doing any recursion?  The ordinary `FilesystemIterator` would be fine.